# Debian 11, multiple Solr versions running on different ports, lsof says that Solr9 is accessible only from localhost.localdomain

Tags: port, solr, lsof, debian-bullseye

I have a Debian 9 server that is running Solr 7.3.
I have upgraded to Debian 11, Solr is still fine.

Now I'm trying to install Solr 9 alongside Solr 7.3, to have both versions running in the same time. I followed the [official guide](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/deployment-guide/taking-solr-to-production.html).

```bash
bash ./install_solr_service.sh solr-9.0.0.tgz -i /opt -d /var/solr9 -u solr -s solr9 -p 8984
```

the installation seems to work fine `systemctl status solr9.service` says

```
● solr9.service - LSB: Controls Apache Solr as a Service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/solr9; generated)
     Active: active (exited) since Mon 2022-11-14 12:43:13 UTC; 4min 47s ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 6781 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/solr9 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Nov 14 12:43:07 xxx systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Controls Apache Solr as a Service...
Nov 14 12:43:13 xxx solr9[6835]: Started Solr server on port 8984 (pid=6830). Happy searching!
Nov 14 12:43:13 xxx systemd[1]: Started LSB: Controls Apache Solr as a Service.
```

but I can't reach Solr9 panel from the browser.

I have checked `iptables --list` and settings for port 8983 (where is running Solr 7.3) are the same of port 8984 (where is running Solr 9).

`lsof -i | grep 8983` says

```
java    5622        solr   37u  IPv6 117480      0t0  TCP *:8983 (LISTEN)
```

but `lsof -i | grep 8984` says

```
java    6830        solr  136u  IPv6 134506      0t0  TCP localhost.localdomain:8984
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the solution, it has nothing to do with running multiple versions of solr, I was having the identical issue on a fresh Debian install.

so the solution is:

open the configuration file `/etc/default/solr.in.sh` (in my case it's `/etc/default/solr9.in.sh`)

append this line

```
SOLR_JETTY_HOST="0.0.0.0"
```

restart the service `systemctl restart solr.service` (in my case it's `systemctl restart solr9.service`)

now finally `lsof -i | grep 8984` says the port it's open

```
java    1952        solr  136u  IPv6  29073      0t0  TCP *:8984 (LISTEN)
```

and finally I can access Solr Admin UI from the browser.

All credits to: https://tecadmin.net/configuring-apache-solr-to-accessible-on-public-ip/